# gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies how to reopen settings?

Tags: cookies, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

Is there a possibility to fire a function that reopens the cookie consent for the user to change the settings?

I implemented the plugin like in the guide
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/

But I can't find a solution to reopen the banner.

I tried to delete the necessary cookie, as it is set always on closing the banner, but this would only open the banner on the next page load and not immediately.

Does anyone know a solution for this?